# How to create html5 canvas for bordered boxes?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create below canvas.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbPjv.png)

my code is below. but I am having trouble to make the canvas look the like the screenshot above. can anyone help me then?

thanks though

```html
<html>
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

<script>
var canvas;
var canvasContext;

window.onload = function() {
 canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
 canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
 canvasContext.fillStyle = 'blue';
 canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
 canvasContext.fillStyle = 'grey';
 canvasContext.fillRect(355,350,120,90);
 canvasContext.fillStyle = 'grey';
 canvasContext.fillRect(190,350,120,90);
 canvasContext.fillStyle = 'grey';
 canvasContext.fillRect(520,350,120,90);
 canvasContext.fillStyle = 'grey';
 canvasContext.fillRect(355,200,120,90);
 canvasContext.fillStyle = 'grey';
 canvasContext.fillRect(190,200,120,90);
 canvasContext.fillStyle = 'grey';
 canvasContext.fillRect(520,200,120,90);
}

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.fillRect` creates a filled region of color. However, `.rect` creates a "shape" that you can then use the `.fill()` and `.stroke()` methods upon.

In the below example if converted creation into a loop for brevity

```
var canvas;
var canvasContext;

window.onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'blue';
    canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    var height = 90;
    var width = 120;
    var leftOffset = 190;
    var topOffset = 200;
    for(var x = 0; x < 6; x++){
        canvasContext.beginPath();
        canvasContext.rect(leftOffset,topOffset,width,height);
        canvasContext.fillStyle = 'grey';
        canvasContext.fill();
        canvasContext.lineWidth = 4;
        canvasContext.strokeStyle = 'lightblue';
        canvasContext.stroke();
        leftOffset += 165;
        if(x === 2){
            leftOffset = 190;
            topOffset = 350;
        }
    }
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cvyyjxab/4/)**

This [tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-rectangles/) on HTML5 Canvas rectangles is very handy

---

To add the text, you would append the following after (or before) the `rect` creating loop

```
canvasContext.beginPath();
canvasContext.font = '20pt Arial';
canvasContext.textAlign = 'center';
canvasContext.fillStyle = 'white';
canvasContext.shadowColor = 'black';
canvasContext.shadowOffsetX = 4;
canvasContext.shadowOffsetY = 4;
canvasContext.fillText('CHOOSE A SCENE TO COLOR', canvas.width/2,55);
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cvyyjxab/6/)**

Tutorials for [text align](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-text-align/), [text shadow](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/texteffects/#toc-text-shadows), and [text](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-text-font-size/).

Comment: And none of these tutos says that you have to use `beginPath`? At every `fill()` or `stroke()`call, you are redrawing previously declared rects, which in fine do compose a single shape, quite heavy for memory + with a lot of artifacts. fixed : https://jsfiddle.net/cvyyjxab/3/ or fixed : https://jsfiddle.net/cvyyjxab/5/

Comment: how to fill each boxes with different color?

Comment: Start with an array of 6 colors and select the one you want using `x`, ie. `var colors = ['grey','red','black','green','orange','purple'];` then later `canvasContext.fillStyle = colors[x];`

Comment: but how to differentiate each boxes based on your code and fill them with different color?

Comment: @DominicCobb, https://jsfiddle.net/cvyyjxab/7/ the order of the colors inside the `colors` array runs from the top left to the bottom right. Given each row has 3 items in it, you can see the top row uses the first 3 colors, then the bottom row uses the next 3 colors.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, use a function to draw a rectangle with exactly the border you want. The trick is to use `.rect` instead of `fillRect` so that you can use `.stroke()` immediately after.

```
<html>
  <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

  <script>
    function draw_bordered_rect(context, x, y, w, h) {
      context.rect(x, y, w, h);
      context.fillStyle = "grey";
      context.fill();

      context.lineWidth = 3;
      context.strokeStyle = "lightblue";
      context.stroke();
    }

    window.onload = function() {
      canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
      canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvasContext.fillStyle = 'blue';
      canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      canvasContext.font = '25pt Arial';
      canvasContext.textAlign = 'center';

      //drop shadow 2px to the left and 2px below the white text
      canvasContext.fillStyle = "black";
      canvasContext.fillText('CHOOSE A SCENE TO COLOR', canvas.width/2-2, 82);

      //actual text ontop of the drop shadow text
      canvasContext.fillStyle = 'white';
      canvasContext.fillText('CHOOSE A SCENE TO COLOR', canvas.width/2, 80);


      draw_bordered_rect(canvasContext, 355, 350, 120, 90);
      draw_bordered_rect(canvasContext, 190, 350, 120, 90);
      draw_bordered_rect(canvasContext, 520, 350, 120, 90);
      draw_bordered_rect(canvasContext, 355, 200, 120, 90);
      draw_bordered_rect(canvasContext, 190, 200, 120, 90);
      draw_bordered_rect(canvasContext, 520, 200, 120, 90);

    }

  </script>

</html>
```

Looks like: [image]

Comment: well thanks. but how about the text? how to put the text in the canvas?

Comment: @DominicCobb, if you wanted to use a shadow, instead of repeated `.fillText` elements, have a look at my answer :)

Comment: btw how can I fill those boxes with different color. what code should be added?

Answer (score 0):

I have some code to design canvas box in `HTML5`. I think you should try this one, I hope it will help you to design your canvas box. I think you should use `JavaScript` mehtod `context.fillRect` as i am giving you [Js Fidler Lind here](http://jsfiddle.net/robhawkes/gHCJt/)

**HTML Code**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="400">
    <!-- Insert fallback content here -->
</canvas>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
var canvas = $("#myCanvas");
var context = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");

// Set rectangle and corner values
var rectX = 50;
var rectY = 50;
var rectWidth = 100;
var rectHeight = 100;
var cornerRadius = 20;

// Reference rectangle without rounding, for size comparison
context.fillRect(200, 50, rectWidth, rectHeight);

// Set faux rounded corners
context.lineJoin = "round";
context.lineWidth = cornerRadius;

// Change origin and dimensions to match true size (a stroke makes the shape a bit larger)
context.strokeRect(rectX+(cornerRadius/2), rectY+(cornerRadius/2), rectWidth-cornerRadius, rectHeight-cornerRadius);
context.fillRect(rectX+(cornerRadius/2), rectY+(cornerRadius/2), rectWidth-cornerRadius, rectHeight-cornerRadius);

// You can do the same thing with paths, like this triangle
// Remember that a stroke will make the shape a bit larger so you'll need to fiddle with the
// coordinates to get the correct dimensions.
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(400, 60);
context.lineTo(440, 140);
context.lineTo(360, 140);
context.closePath();
context.stroke();
context.fill();
```

This javascript code will design canvas box just like below g]iven image
[image]